# How to read the crash utility output for source line numbers?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am working on my embedded application on Ubuntu 16.0.4. I have written a fan monitoring driver for my board. The driver faults the kernel and system has to be rebooted.
I enabled kdump and using crash utility to analyze the stack trace.
For me the trace looks like:

```
crash> bt
PID: 2935   TASK: c01a8000  CPU: 3   COMMAND: "mk7i"
#0 [e309ddbc] crash_kexec at c10fa4ce
#1 [e309de1c] path_openat at c11e812b
#2 [e309de94] do_page_fault at c105de55
#3 [e309dea4] error_code (via page_fault) at c17a9185
EAX: 00000400  EBX: 037ea1e0  ECX: f0a746c4  EDX: 00000000  EBP: e309df00 
DS:  007b      ESI: 00000000  ES:  007b      EDI: e3f47000  GS:  00e0
CS:  0060      EIP: f0a718f4  ERR: ffffffff  EFLAGS: 00210212 
#4 [e309ded8] fmon_read_value at f0a718f4 [fmon]
#5 [e309dee8] security_file_permission at c12f73ae
#6 [e309df04] proc_reg_read at c1239c2b
#7 [e309df24] __vfs_read at c11da81d
#8 [e309df38] vfs_read at c11dae8a
#9 [e309df5c] sys_read at c11db92c
#10 [e309df84] do_fast_syscall_32 at c1003936
#11 [e309dfb0] sysenter_past_esp at c17a8093
EAX: ffffffda  EBX: 00000012  ECX: 037ea1e0  EDX: 00000400 
DS:  007b      ESI: 037f6360  ES:  007b      EDI: ffffff98
SS:  007b      ESP: a802a834  EBP: a802a888  GS:  0033
CS:  0073      EIP: b76f8c31  ERR: 00000003  EFLAGS: 00200292
```

The function "fmon_read_value" , that causes fault is in my driver module.
I would like to know how can I map the address in that function/module to source line number ? In this case, the address being **f0a718f4**

Answer (score 0):

you could use gdb to find the line using gdb frame for example.

Here is probably a good documentation how to do that:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelDebuggingTricks#Using_GDB_to_find_the_location_where_your_kernel_panicked_or_oopsed.

Answer (score 0):

The "-l" option for disassemble will do the trick. For example:
   crash> dis -lr f0a718f4